# sqldeveloper + voltdb connection

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, voltdb

I want to create a database connection for voltdb using sqldeveloper like mysql,db2.. but didnt do it.

Because i can not see "database tab" on sqldeveloper as db2 or oracle or mysql..
My way ise
 tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party Drivers. thirdpary jdbc driver

add entry then import voltdbclient.jar..(8.4.1)

I did this way for db2 with own db2jcc-db2jcc4.jar  can see "database tab" for  db2..

But i can not see voltdb tab for connection...and i can not connect to voltdb.

Do you have a suggestion for me to see voltdb tab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support that driver/platform for migrations, so you won't see a VoltDB panel for their jdbc driver.